# jQuery .hover function troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-hover

I recently tried my first jQuery for the menu of this site.
- The menu works correctly **But** I only want it to show up when I hover on the three images on the left, not the whole (hidden) div.

I have tried to re-create this in jsfiddle but was unsuccessful, sorry.

Here is a video of what I'm talking about:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wmCOiVnY-0E&feature=youtu.be

Here is the site:
http://www.actualizestudio.com/dev/dcworks/

Any help would really be appreciated as I am not a jQuery pro.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code here.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.design').hover(function(){
   $(this).next().fadeIn();
});
```

That will show the div directly after the div with the left hand image (i.e. the menu div)